# Metric Space Distance Question

Tags: real-analysis

for metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on a nonempty set $X$, suppose there are positive constants $a$ and $b$ such that $ad_1(x,y) \le d_2(x,y) \le bd_1(x,y), \forall x,y \in X$. Prove that a subset $U$ of $X$ is open in $(X,d_1)$ if and only if it is open in $(X,d_2)$.
I cannot seem to get far in this question, because I feel like I'm doing something wrong with the constants. If  a set's open in $U$ with metric $d_1$, does that mean it's open in $a*d_1$?

Comment: You can do that directly with balls. Maybe you will find it easier to prove that the complement $U^c=X\setminus U$ is (sequentially) closed wrt $d_1$ iff it is (sequentially) closed wrt $d_2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

It suffices to prove that every ball $B(c,r)$ of $(X,d_1)$ is contained in a ball $B(c,r')$ of $(X,d_2)$ and conversely.

Comment: Now when you say $B(a,r)$, are you expressing $a$ as a point, or the constant value?

Comment: $B(a,r)$ is the ball with center $a$ and radius $r$.

Comment: So you've centered a ball around the constant $a$ in which $ad_1 \le d_2$? I thought $a$ was simply a scalar, not necessarily a point in $U$.

Comment: Since $a$ and $b$ are used as  reals I edited my answer and the center is denoted by $c$

Comment: Oh alright, that makes more sense. Also, when you say that 'every ball...is containing in a ball,' do you mean 'is containing in it a ball,' or 'is contained in a ball'?

Comment: In this discussion I learn from you English and I correct my mistakes:-) and what I meant the ball is contained in another ball but the converse meaning is also true

Comment: $\ddot\smile +1$